# Wordpress images does not exist in upload folder but is showing in media library

Tags: wordpress, image, file-upload, upload, directory

I have found a very strange problem on my wordpress/woocommerce site.

I made a copy with the plugin Duplicator, to make some changes in a localhost environment.
My uploads folder is too big, so I unset it to be copied by Duplicator. To get all the images I simply copied all files and subfolders in /uploads folder to my localhost /uploads folder. After that wordpress finds only few images. The rest doesn't exist.

To make sure I haven't missed something during the copy process, I checked the /uploads folder on my live site. And there the same image files doesn't exist. Even if the path in the media library says they are in the /uploads folder.

So the big question is, where are the images they doesn't exist in the /uploads folder? 
Is wordpress capable to store images in the database?

Comment: Wordpress is storing the image url not the image. Can you let me know which other plugins you are having active in same website.

Comment: That's the process I use to copy a site using Duplicator (i.e. copy the uploads folder separately) and it works fine, so the way you did it isn't a problem. Have you checked the url for the broken image - is it correct or is it looking for it in the wrong place?

Comment: Thank you for your time to help me. I ve found the issue. It is the limitation of the ftp protocol. It is set to "only" show 10000 files. I use Filezilla for up and downloads. In my cpanel backend I ve seen that there are all images in the /uploads folder ;) Unfortunately my hoster doesn't offer sftp. So I have to use the cpanel backend.

Answer (score 1):

Media files exist in upload folder but not showing up solution
Simply Paste this code in wpconfig.php and save it all is done :)

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'uploads' );
```